# Salesforce data table causes UI to be slow

Tags: user-interface, components, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Salesforce custom object lightning page has 40+ fields with one data table. When Data table has more than 500 records it causes the whole UI to response very slowly. Checkbox changes checked or unchecked takes 2 seconds. If you type in textbox it responses 3/4 seconds to populate the value. If I limit the records to 500 it improves but still not normal response time.